# Displaying "No Results Found" in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to display no results found if the search term by the user doesn't matches any result from the database.
I have gone through various questions on here, but none helped me.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {


        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor );
         window.location.href = './company.php?id=' + ui.item.indexid + '&name=' + ui.item.label;

      }
    });
  });



  </script>
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What's `search.php`?  Do you see anything if you look in your browser's network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: is this jqueryUI, or what plugin are you using?

Comment: @dave: I'm assuming jQuery UI since the code shown is just the code from the example page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Look at these: [Detecting no results on jQuery UI autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718968/detecting-no-results-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete) and [jQuery UI autocomplete, show something when no results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141945/jquery-ui-autocomplete-show-something-when-no-results).

Comment: search.php is the file which processes the search term.

Comment: Why isn't this line getting displayed `"Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor` when there are no results.

Comment: @user3727339: What does it look like?  What does it print?

Comment: @user3727339: What debugging have you tried?  What does `console.log(ui);` show?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uH5zb/6/) in which you loop through the returned data inside of "response:" and when you get an array with length == 0, it fills in the input field with "No matches" or anything else you'd want.

And just to throw out an idea, if the dataset is small enough, you can read the all the data from the db, then do the autocomplete.

JS

```
var areas = ['california', 'nevada', 'oregon', 'utah', 'arizona', 'new mexico', 'minnesota', 'texas', 'louisiana', 'alabama', 'mississippi', 'oklahoma'];

$('.autocomp').autocomplete({
    autoFocus : true,
    source : areas,
    selectFirst : true,
    response: function( event, ui ) {
                                     var count = 0;
                                     console.log( ui.content.length );
                                     for (var n=0; n < ui.content.length + 1; n++)
                                     {
                                      if( ui.content.length == 0 )
                                      {
                                       $('.autocomp').val('No results');
                                       } else {
                                       count = count+1;
                                               }
                                       }
                                      }
});
```